# Change Price based on Select Option for Configurable products

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product

I have a product and three variations.  So, when I change the options for the Size,  I want to change the price dynamically for that option. For.eg.  we have Standanrd,  Large and X Large.  And price is 15, 30 and 46 Resp.  When Selecting Large, the price change to 30 and so on.

I read a lot in the Stackexchange or internet but could not find a right solution.  The sample link to the page is http://bibliografi.co.uk/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/8262/s/COP090709009/

in View.phtml I have this

```
var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
```

and to display the price

```
          <tr valign="top">
            <td>Price:</td>
            <td><strong>
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, false) ?>
            <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?></strong></td>
          </tr>
```

any help please

Comment: You can add that price in admin panel it self.

Comment: visit:-www.magesolution.com/blog/techniques-show-product-options-in-product-list/ give solustion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its default functionality of magento, set main configurable product price with $15(min price) and set extra price with "Super product attributes configuration" section.Please check below attachment and let us know if you need more detail.

[image]